# uploading laravel-8 project in 000webhost error

Tags: web, hosting, web-hosting, laravel-8, host

I am trying to upload my laravel-8 project in 000webhost.com  but my Public folder and resources and storage and routes and tests and vendor folder not uploading. I make my whole project in a zip folder and upload it public_html and extract my project than those folders not showing. but in my zip file, those folders and files are present what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

i have this issue recently. Try to do this.

1st, open your laravel-8 project file and select all files except "node_modules".

2nd, right click and zip (make sure that the archiving method is .zip because 000webhost can't extract RAR archives.

for better understanding, open this link below:
https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/deploy-laravel-project-on-000webhost/127323